# real time in python subprocess not working on windows console

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, real-time, windows-console

I'm trying to run one python script(Activator) that will run another script(client)  and terminate it after a certain time cap. (5 seconds in this example).

Activator

```html
import random, sys, os, socket
import time, datetime
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Queue


class deamon_pckg:
    def __init__(self, msg_type, info, exeption=None):
        self.msg_type = msg_type
        self.info = info
        self.exception = exeption


class Process_comm:
    @staticmethod
    def deamon(process, q):
        while process.poll() is None:
            out = process.stdout.readline().rstrip()
            if out != '':
                d_pckg = deamon_pckg('cmd', out)
                q.put(d_pckg)

        exit_code = process.returncode
        if exit_code != 0:
            err_msg = process.stderr.read()
        else:
            err_msg = None
        d_pckg = deamon_pckg('EXIT', exit_code, err_msg)
        q.put(d_pckg)

    def __init__(self, process):
        self.process = process
        self.q = Queue()
        self.d = Thread(target=Process_comm.deamon, args=(self.process, self.q))
        self.d.start()

    def close(self):
        if self.process.returncode is None:
            self.terminate()
        self.d.join()

    def terminate(self):
        self.process.terminate()

    def get(self, blocking=False):
        if blocking:
            return self.q.get()
        else:
            if self.q.empty():
                return None
            else:
                return self.q.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Activator online"
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', "C:\work\Router\src\demiborg.py"],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    d = Process_comm(process)


    while True:
        delta = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
        dpckg = d.get()
        if delta.seconds >= 5:
            d.terminate()
            break
        if dpckg is None:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            if dpckg.msg_type == 'EXIT':
                print "[{}]\t{}".format(dpckg.msg_type, dpckg.info)
                if dpckg.exception is not None:
                    print "{}".format(dpckg.exception)
                break
            else:
                print "[{}]\t{}".format(dpckg.msg_type, dpckg.info)
    d.close()
```

Client:

```html
import random, sys, os, socket
import time, datetime


def get_time_stamp():
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%f:%S:%M:%H:%d:%m:%Y')
    return st

def put(fout,msg):
    fout.write('[{:>30}]'.format(get_time_stamp()) + '\t' + msg + '\n')
    fout.flush
    print msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fout = open('demiborg.txt','wb')
    put(fout,"Start DemiBorg")
    for i in range(20):
        put(fout,"time - {}".format(i))
        time.sleep(0.5)

    put(fout,'End')
    fout = open('ERROR', 'wb')
    fout.close()
```

If i run

```html
Activator online
[cmd] Start DemiBorg
[cmd] time - 0
[cmd] time - 1
[cmd] time - 2
[cmd] time - 3
[cmd] time - 4
[cmd] time - 5
[cmd] time - 6
[cmd] time - 7
[cmd] time - 8
[cmd] time - 9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when i run it via the windows console i get no input at all (like the client didn't run).

```html
C:\work\Router\src>C:\work\Router\src\plygrnd_activator.py
Activator online

C:\work\Router\src>
```

further more , if a didn't kill the client , i noticed that all the messages came as one block together only after the client finished the run. why only using pycharm it works fine but on the console i don't get live feedback? 
the purpose is to run on console. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution, the problem was in the buffer size.

instead of using :

```html
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', "C:\work\Router\src\demiborg.py"],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

i've added "-u" flag after the "python":

```html
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u', "C:\work\Router\src\demiborg.py"],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```